# IO Error creating local socket when running ContentProvider in its own process

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

### Background

I have a shared `ContentProvider` + `SQLiteDatabase` model in the app.

This `ContentProvider` is running fine when it is sharing the same process with the app. However, `IOException` is thrown if I make it runs in its own process (declaring `android:process`).

The exception thrown doesn't cause any app crash issue, I just want to know why this is happening and whether its possible to prevent it from happening.

### How to trigger

1. Single query through `CursorLoader`.
2. Single query through `ContentResolver`.

### Questions

1. Why would `ContentProvider` attempts to create a "local socket"?
2. Why would "Address already in use" occurs when I am making only ONE query that should at most attempt to create the "local socket" once?
3. Is it possible to avoid this Exception from being triggered?

### Manifest `<provider>`

```
<provider
    android:name="com.demo.sharedprovider.SharedProvider"
    android:authorities="com.demo.sharedprovider.provider"
    android:permission="com.demo.sharedprovider.PROVIDER"
    android:process=":provider" />
```

### Stack trace

```
com.demo.sharedprovider:provider E/InstantRun: IO Error creating local socket at com.demo.sharedprovider
                                               java.io.IOException: Address already in use
                                                   at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.bindLocal(Native Method)
                                                   at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.bind(LocalSocketImpl.java:306)
                                                   at android.net.LocalServerSocket.<init>(LocalServerSocket.java:48)
                                                   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.<init>(Server.java:94)
                                                   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.create(Server.java:88)
                                                   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.onCreate(BootstrapApplication.java:303)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: any reason for using `android:process`?

Comment: @pskink This `ContentProvider` is supposed to expose to any app that wants access to it.

Comment: any `ContentProvider` will do that if it is `android:enabled` and `android:exported` (both by default are true), no reason for `android:process`

Comment: @pskink I couldn't agree less, just that the same problem occurs if you are accessing it from another app (different process).

Comment: hmmm, try from the minimal `ContactProvider` then, (just return empty `Cursor` from `query`, no permissions etc)

Comment: @pskink Sorry I don't get what you mean. Can you please post your suggestion as answer with more information? Thank you..

Comment: create a simple `ContentProvider` again (using android studio for example) do not implement your db stuff (return null in `query` for example) and test it in another app, if it works try adding db stuff and check it again

Comment: @pskink I have tried it, the manifest and the stack trace (in the post) are extracted from the sample app.

Comment: so the minimal ContentProvider does not work as well?

Comment: @pskink Not that it does not work, just that there is an Exception thrown and I want to know why is this happening.

Comment: ok first turn InstantRun off, then try again